# How do I change my UserId on Apple Developer Forums?

Tags: apple-id

How do I change my userid on the Apple Developer Forums?  As shown in the below screenshot, it seems there is no way to change this. Do I need to simply call Apple support?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

You'll need to contact [Apple Developer Account Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php). However, in most cases you will get an answer as *once your account is created, you will not be able to change your username that appeared when creating a username, and suggest registering a new Apple ID for the developer.*

So, if you don't care, you can probably create a new user.

Or at least first give a try asking Apple Developer Account Support team.

Answer (score 0):

I called Apple Developer support and was informed that I am not able to change my developer forum userID as it is tied to my Apple ID.  That is fine.  I cam live with it.